# Looking for unix command to reverse sort a file based on date column

Tags: sorting, unix

2nd column of the file is date.
Looking for unix command to sort(descending) a file based on date column

```
cat file1.txt | column -t

5.13.0.18S    2023-07-21_13:23:39  Activated  Previous
5.13.0.19S    2023-07-21_13:54:03  Activated  Current
5.13.0.17S    2023-07-21_13:09:48  Activated  Antecedent
5.13.0.16S    2023-07-21_12:57:04  Activated  Outdated 
5.13.0.15S    2023-07-21_07:37:24  NA         Outdated
```

Date format can be updated if needed as I am getting date value from a Oracle procedure

Comment: Reverse Sorting on column 2 can be done: `cat file1.txt | column -t | sort -k 2 -r`  (more info see: `man sort`)

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question is: read `man sort`

see: [man sort](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html)

most important options (for this question):

> -k, --key=KEYDEF
> sort via a key; KEYDEF gives location and type

> -r, --reverse
> reverse the result of comparisons